# CORS error calling DynamoDB from Alexa Skill Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to create an Alexa Skill that will query a DynamoDB table from an AWS Lambda function, but I'm getting the error (shown below) when I try to use the get function.

I can't find any place to add a CORS header or specify I don't need one.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
const params = {
            TableName: "test-sds",
            Key: slotValues.chemical.heardAs,
            projectionExpression: [
                slotValues.id_info.heardAs,
            ],
        };    
        dynamoDb.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('************'+err);
            }
             else {
                 console.log('answer: '+ data.response.data);
             }
             //.speak(data.response.data)}
        })
```

This is the error message I'm receiving in the Alexa Developer Console when I test the skill:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://avs-alexa-na.amazon.com/v20160207/directives' from origin 'https://developer.amazon.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How do I configure DynamoDB to support CORS, or specify that I don't need it?

Comment: You have to put the CORS header in the response.

Comment: If all I'm using is the get method for DynamoDB and I don't need to write a response, where do I set a response header?

Comment: You are getting a response. By definition, a GET request gives you a response.

Comment: I'm only getting an error response, the get is failing because of the missing CORS header. Is there somewhere in the AWS DynamoDB configuration that I can set a CORS header?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think the previous commenters are on the wrong track. 
 To clarify: you are getting a CORS error calling Dynamo DB.  You aren't crafting a response, simply calling 'get' forDynamoDB and getting the error?  Correct?  So the question is how do you configure CORS for DynamoDB?